# Launch program with xinit with parameters

Tags: bash, parameters, xserver

is there anyway to launch an application by xinit with parameters ?

Currently I am able to do this :

```
xinit libreoffice -- :1
```

And I would like to do something like :

```
xinit libreoffice /home/user/Desktop/file.odt -- :1
```

ty

Answer (score 0):

You can pack the command into a bash script and then start it using xinit. For PDF viewer it worked for me as follows:

script.sh:

`xpdf -geometry 700x700+0+0 -remote pdfServer /path/to/file/test.pdf`

then start it using:

```
xinit /path/to/script/script.sh -- :1
```